# How to just autorun a single program via SSH?

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to forbid the interactive shell login for a user an instead run a predefined programm ?

In my case I wrote a program on the server that counts down to a specific time. I want to create a user that does not have an interactive shell but can login to watch this program

Im not quite sure if the question is clear ? If you know those telnet movies you will maybe understand what i want to achieve.

--

Maybe an example helps. If I have the following C-Program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  while(1){
      time ( &rawtime );
      printf ( "\rCurrent timestamp: %ld", rawtime );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

i want to have possibilty that one can login without a password to watch the output of this program, but cant do anything else.

Comment: "watch the program" or "RUN the program"? if you want it to run on login, then make that program be the user's shell. e.g. change the shell definition in /etc/passwd to /usr/bin/yourapp instead of /bin/sh

Comment: Okay, i know how to run a program, maybe this was unclear in the question. Changing the Shell to the Programm seems to force the user to use only this program.

Comment: as per your example, can't really bypass the password prompt, but you can create an account with NO password (e.g. just hit enter), and if you make the compiled binary of that time display be the user's shell, they'd get the time output scrolling by after they hit enter on the password line.

Comment: It would be nice if one does not even have to see the password dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The feasible goal and approach is:
 1. When you run your program, your redirect its output to certain file

2. Setup an ssh account with "Forced command". Please check ssh manual for detailed info. Basically, you are setting up a pub-key authentication for that account so that no password needed and you specify the allowed command to "auto run" after login. In your case, that command would be some like "tail -f the_log_file"